# DC bias of waveform

Tags: oscillator

I have a waveform which is built from a math function. I want to repeat it to make a oscillator.

Now to offset it to remove dc bias, do I just make total area equal zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DC bias is just the non-zero mean of a signal.

So, calculate the mean, and then subtract that.

Now, calculating a mean is done by summing things up (discrete thinking) / integrating (continuous thinking) and dividing by the length – it's possible that you mean that with "area", but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: With area I just mean integrating, yes.